# JSON Object Value Show Undefine

Tags: php, jquery, javascript, json

I have the following PHP array which I encode to JSON as seen in the snippet of my code below:

```
$user_info = [
    "user_name"     => $current_user->user_login,
    "user_email"    => $current_user->user_email,
    "user_id"       => $current_user->ID,
    "user_comment"  => $message
];

json_encode( $user_info );
```

When I run a `console.log()` of the encoded `$user_info` variable above, I get the JSON below:

```
{
  "user_name": "admin",
  "user_email": "admin@exmple.com",
  "user_id": 1,
  "user_comment": ""
}
```

My problem now is that, when I narrow down to the `user_name` value, I get an *undefine* error.

Below is my approach:

```
// response is a declared variable which holds the encoded $user_info PHP array above
console.log( data.user_name );
```

The following image is a screenshot of my browser, showing my console.

[image: Browser, showing both view and console]

And here, that of my PHP code (circled in yellow, the actual portion regarding my post).

[image: PHP code (circled in yellow)]

My full JavaScript code is as follow:

```
$("#txt-cmt").keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    var comment = $(this).val();
    var message = {
      action: 'show_comment',
      user_message: comment
    };
    $.post(ajaxUrl.url, message, function(data) {
      console.log(data.user_name);
    });
  }
});
```

What am I possibly doing wrong and how can I fix it so as to get my code working as expected?

Comment: When you run `console.log(data);` instead of `console.log(data.user_name);` in your `$.post`; what is the exact result you get?

Comment: hey nyedidikeke, i get undefine  result, but  i want user name

Comment: Just as expected @abdul; `data` wasn't defined. Quick questions: 1. how is your JavaScript file related to your PHP script? 2. Can you describe what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: @nyedidikeke  data is defined , data.user_name is show undefined, when i console.log(typeof data); it's show string then i  use JSON.parse(data); but it's show this error     
jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4 XHR finished loading: POST "http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php".
send @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4
ajax @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4
n.(anonymous function) @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4
(anonymous) @ comment-mu.js?ver=4.7.5:25
dispatch @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3
r.handle @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3

Comment: We are not on the same page @abdul; you said the opposite earlier! let's start all over again: **When you run `console.log(data);` instead of `console.log(data.user_name);` in your `$.post`; what is the exact result you get?**

Comment: when i run `console.log(data);` i get result like this `{"user_name": "admin", "user_email":"admin@exmple.com", "user_id": 1,"user_comment": ""}` but when i run `console.log(data.user_name)` i get      undefined hope you understand my problem @nyedidikeke

Comment: I do. Just answered you below.

Comment: *You should avoid cross-posting across other stack exchange sites Abdul: it is highly discouraged.*

Answer (score 0):

You either need to tell jQuery that you expect a `json` response from the server:

```
$("#txt-cmt").keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    var comment = $(this).val();
    var message = {
      action: 'show_comment',
      user_message: comment
    };
    $.post(ajaxUrl.url, message, function(data) {
      console.log(data.user_name);
    }, 'json');
  }
});
```

or you need to parse the response as json with [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Comment: not working, and if i use JSON.parse() method 

i got this error

jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4 XHR finished loading: POST "http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php".
send @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4

ajax @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4
n.(anonymous function) @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4
(anonymous) @ comment-mu.js?ver=4.7.5:25
dispatch @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3
r.handle @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3

Comment: What did you try exactly? Update your question with your current code. The simplest method is the first, but if you use JSON.parse instead, you have to assign the result- `data = JSON.parse(data)`. If `console.log(typeof data);` says string, I can guarantee you that this is your problem.

Comment: when i use data = JSON.parse(data); i got error like below

`/wordpress/#:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (comment-mu.js?ver=4.7.5:26)
    at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at y (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4)`

Comment: If you set the datatype parameter, then you don't need JSON.parse. You have to do one OR the other, not both.

Comment: this code also not working :(

Comment: You are not understanding or implementing it correctly. Edit your question and show what you've tried. Add your complete code so someone can copy and paste it to test. I am done trying to help you otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

In such a situation, instead of `die(json_encode($user_info));`, I will

```
echo json_encode($user_info);
wp_die();
```

Try this to see if there's a difference.

Comment: i also try this but not working :(

Comment: Did you also die() after ?

Comment: yes  i also use `die();  wp_die()` :(  not working

Answer (score 0):

You first need to parse `data` before you can get your `user_name`.

Below is a commented snippet to walk you through:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    console.log( "ready!" );

    $( "#txt-cmt" ).keypress(function( e ) {
      if ( e.which == 13 ) {
        var comment = $( this ).val();
        var message = {
          action: 'show_comment',
          user_message: comment
        };
        $.post(ajaxUrl.url, message, function( data ) {
        // Your data in it's raw form
        // Expected result: {"user_name": "admin", "user_email":"admin@exmple.com", "user_id": 1,"user_comment": ""}
        console.log( "raw data" );
        console.log( data );

        // Here, declare a new variable to hold your parsed data
        // Expected result: a JSON object {user_name: "admin", user_email: "admin@exmple.com", user_id: 1, user_comment: ""}
        var parseData = JSON.parse( data );
        console.log( "parse data" );
        console.log( parseData );

        // After that, you can get your user_name using either of the options below;
        // they both work

        // Option one
        // Expected result: admin
        console.log( "option one" );
        console.log( parseData.user_name );

        // Option two
        // Expected result: admin
        // console.log( "option two" );
        // console.log( parseData['user_name'] );
        })

        .done(function( data ) {
          // What to do after the post is successful goes here
          console.log( "sort of a second success" );
        })

        .fail(function( data ) {
          // What to do only if an error occurred goes here
          console.log( "an error occurred" );
        })

        .always(function( data ) {
          // What to always do, whether the post was successful or an error occurred goes here
          console.log( "the post request has finished running, whether with a success or failure" );
        });
      }
    });
});
```